# Doctrine migrations:diff ignores cascade

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have ManyToOne relation between two entities and would like to use DB (MySQL) level cascade on delete.  When I use doctrine:migrations:diff foreign key is created without ON DELETE CASCADE.

So I added this cascade myself but on next migrations:diff this statement has been removed. Is there any way how I can use DB level cascade on delete along with doctrine:migrations?

```
class System {

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Cost", mappedBy="system", cascade={"remove"})
     */
    private $costs;
}

class Cost {
    /**
     * @var System
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="System", inversedBy="costs", cascade={"remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="system_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $system;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this instead in your JoinColumn annotation:

```
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="system_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
```

For more information - [the documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#removing-entities).